# A differentiation to matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I was confused about whether a differentiation to matrix is a differentiation to every elements of the matrix.
For example a $2\times2$ matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial b}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial c}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial d}{\partial x}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generically true that 
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial b}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial c}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial d}{\partial x}
\end{pmatrix} \, . $$

Answer (score 0):

This depends very much on context. What are $a,b,c,d$ defined to be in the text you are reading?

The matrix could for example very well represent a couple of linear functions $\cases{y_1=ax+b\\y_2= cx+d}$ and then what would the derivative be?